# JS Custom Color Picker

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Basically lol cant add videos here but with the default html color picker you can move the color picker dot if mouse is down off the colors box boundries and it moves agains the edge of the boundries but with mine it just stops moving and doesnt do good when i move the mouse fast.**

I am trying to create a custom color picker where you have a slider of colors, then you have the box of the color selected and you can change the whiteness and darkness of it like this here (Like adobe xdcc color picker):
[Adobe xdcc color picker example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Q3r.png)

[The code below creates this here][2]
You can drag the little color picker circle and it changes the selected color but when using canvas I can't have to color picker circle moving around the edges when the mouse leaves the canvas which i would like to change.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Let's Create a Color Picker</h2>
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="color-picker"></canvas>
  <div class="info">
    <h3>Selected Color</h3> 
    <div class="selected"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-family: Oxygen, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;   }
         .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;   }
         #color-picker {
        border: .5px solid rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.2);   }
         .info {
        width: 12em;
        display: flex;
        margin-left: 4em;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;   }
         .selected {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        border: 2px solid rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.2);   }
```

JS:

```
    class Picker {
        constructor(target, width, height) {
          this.target = target;
          this.width = width;
          this.height = height;
          this.target.width = width;
          this.target.height = height;
          // Get context 
          this.context = this.target.getContext("2d");
          // Circle 
          this.pickerCircle = { x: 10, y: 10, width: 10, height: 10 };
          
          this.listenForEvents();
        }
        
        draw() {
        }
        
        build() {
          let gradient = this.context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, this.width, 0);
      
          //Color Stops
          gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
          gradient.addColorStop(0.15, "rgb(255, 0, 255)");
          gradient.addColorStop(0.33, "rgb(0, 0, 255)");
          gradient.addColorStop(0.49, "rgb(0, 255, 255)");
          gradient.addColorStop(0.67, "rgb(0, 255, 0)");
          gradient.addColorStop(0.84, "rgb(255, 255, 0)");
          gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
          //Fill it
          this.context.fillStyle = gradient;
          this.context.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
          
          //Apply black and white 
              gradient = this.context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0,          this.height);
          gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)");
          gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)");
          gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
          gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)");
          this.context.fillStyle = gradient;
          this.context.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
          
          //Circle 
          this.context.beginPath();
          this.context.arc(this.pickerCircle.x, this.pickerCircle.y, this.pickerCircle.width, 0, Math.PI * 2);
          this.context.strokeStyle = "black";
          this.context.stroke();
          this.context.closePath();
          
        }
        
        listenForEvents() {
          let isMouseDown = false;
          const onMouseDown = (e) => {
              this.build();
              let currentX = e.clientX - this.target.offsetLeft;
            let currentY = e.clientY - this.target.offsetTop;
              this.pickerCircle.x = currentX;
              this.pickerCircle.y = currentY;
              isMouseDown = true;
            }
          
          const onMouseMove = (e) => {
            if(isMouseDown) {
              this.build();
              let currentX = e.clientX - this.target.offsetLeft;
             let currentY = e.clientY - this.target.offsetTop;
              this.pickerCircle.x = currentX;
              this.pickerCircle.y = currentY;
            }
          }
          
          const onMouseUp = () => {
            isMouseDown = false;
          }
          
          //Register 
          this.target.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);
          this.target.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
          this.target.addEventListener("mousemove", () => this.onChangeCallback(this.getPickedColor()));
      
          
          document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
        }
        
        getPickedColor() {
          let imageData = this.context.getImageData(this.pickerCircle.x, this.pickerCircle.y, 1, 1);
          return { r: imageData.data[0], g: imageData.data[1], b: imageData.data[2] };
        }
        
        onChange(callback) {
          this.onChangeCallback = callback;
        }
        
           }
         let picker = new Picker(document.getElementById("color-picker"), 250, 220);    picker.build();
    
      picker.onChange((color) => {
         let selected = document.getElementsByClassName("selected")[0];
        selected.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${color.r}, ${color.g}, ${color.b})`;   });


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQsjs.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/krEYa.png
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :).

Answer (score 0):

the solution is simple, dont use the `if(isMouseDown){..}`, because that will make your code very unresponsive, so what I did is that I declared a varable `let i = 0;` then on the `onMouseDown`, whenever that function is called, it will increment the value of `i` and I changed the `onMouseMove` from `if(isMouseDown){..}` to `if(i % 2 === 0){..}` heres my solution:

```js
class Picker {
        constructor(target, width, height) {
          this.target = target;
          this.width = width;
          this.height = height;
          this.target.width = width;
          this.target.height = height;
          //Get context
          this.context = this.target.getContext("2d");
          //Circle
          this.pickerCircle = { x: 10, y: 10, width: 10, height: 10 };
          
          this.listenForEvents();
        }
        
        draw() {
        }
        
        build() {
          let gradient = this.context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, this.width, 0);
      
          //Color Stops
          gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
          gradient.addColorStop(0.15, "rgb(255, 0, 255)");
          gradient.addColorStop(0.33, "rgb(0, 0, 255)");
          gradient.addColorStop(0.49, "rgb(0, 255, 255)");
          gradient.addColorStop(0.67, "rgb(0, 255, 0)");
          gradient.addColorStop(0.84, "rgb(255, 255, 0)");
          gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
          //Fill it
          this.context.fillStyle = gradient;
          this.context.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
          
          //Apply black and white
              gradient = this.context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0,          this.height);
          gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)");
          gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)");
          gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
          gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)");
          this.context.fillStyle = gradient;
          this.context.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
          
          //Circle
          this.context.beginPath();
          this.context.arc(this.pickerCircle.x, this.pickerCircle.y, this.pickerCircle.width, 0, Math.PI * 2);
          this.context.strokeStyle = "black";
          this.context.stroke();
          this.context.closePath();
          
        }
        
        listenForEvents() {
          let isMouseDown = true;
          let i =0;
          const onMouseDown = (e) => {
              this.build();
              isMouseDown = true
              i++
              let currentX = e.clientX - this.target.offsetLeft;
            let currentY = e.clientY - this.target.offsetTop;
              this.pickerCircle.x = currentX;
              this.pickerCircle.y = currentY;
             
            }
          
          const onMouseMove = (e) => {
            if(i%2 == 0) {
              this.build();
              let currentX = e.clientX - this.target.offsetLeft;
             let currentY = e.clientY - this.target.offsetTop;
              this.pickerCircle.x = currentX;
              this.pickerCircle.y = currentY;
            }
          }
          
          const onMouseUp = () => {
            
                isMouseDown = false;


            
          }
          
          //Register
          this.target.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);
          this.target.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
          this.target.addEventListener("mousemove", () => this.onChangeCallback(this.getPickedColor()));
      
          
          document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
        }
        
        getPickedColor() {
          let imageData = this.context.getImageData(this.pickerCircle.x, this.pickerCircle.y, 1, 1);
          return { r: imageData.data[0], g: imageData.data[1], b: imageData.data[2] };
        }
        
        onChange(callback) {
          this.onChangeCallback = callback;
        }
        
           }
         let picker = new Picker(document.getElementById("color-picker"), 250, 220);    picker.build();
    
      picker.onChange((color) => {
         let selected = document.getElementsByClassName("selected")[0];
        selected.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${color.r}, ${color.g}, ${color.b})`;   });
```

```css
 html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-family: Oxygen, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;   }
         .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;   }
         #color-picker {
        border: .5px solid rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.2);   }
         .info {
        width: 12em;
        display: flex;
        margin-left: 4em;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;   }
         .selected {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        border: 2px solid rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.2);   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Let's Create a Color Picker</h2>
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="color-picker"></canvas>
  <div class="info">
    <h3>Selected Color</h3>
    <div class="selected"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that it did fix a few things but one other thing is that on  most other color pickers it allows you to move the picker dot whilst off the canavas like around the edges if that makes sense is there a way to do this ? or would I have to re create the picker without the canvas?

Comment: The `mouseover` event should help you solve it, [MDN mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript/Mouse_controls)

Comment: Hey, I took a look but didn't seem to do a lot and maybe im explaining my self bad ha ha never asked for help on a forum before so I made two videos first one is what I am trying to do and second one is what I have so far any help is appreciated. I will edit the main question to hopefully explain my self better.